# Activity orientation change while in the background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, orientation

The first activity(locked portrait orientation) has 2 buttons that both open the second activity but **A** button opens it in portrait and **B** button opens it in landscape orientation.

**The problem** is that  when **B** button opens the second activity (*which is in dialog configuration and the first activity is shown in the background*) the first activity  changes orientation with the second one, thus restarting.

**The question** is, A) Can i prevent first activity from changing orientation and B) Can i disable orientation change animation so that the screen doesn't look  like turning from portrait to landscape but just becoming landscape instead?

P.S For the A) question i know how to use saved state but i want to avoid it.

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" in the manifest for A will prevent A from restarting when back is pressed, but it won't prevent A being shown in landscape under the dialog themed B...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below Code in Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" 
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

**Edited:**
Sorry there is no way to control the rotation animation. This is done way outside of your app, deep in the window manager where it takes a screenshot of the current screen, resizes and rebuilds the UI behind it, and then runs a built-in animation to transition from the original screenshot to the new rebuilt UI. There is no way to modify this behavior when the screen rotation changes

Comment: Sorry there is no way to control the rotation animation. This is done way outside of your app, deep in the window manager where it takes a screenshot of the current screen, resizes and rebuilds the UI behind it, and then runs a built-in animation to transition from the original screenshot to the new rebuilt UI. There is no way to modify this behavior when the screen rotation changes.

Comment: Change your answer to the comment above so i can click solved